# Android Dialogue box crashes App

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am making an activity that has to display a registration form as a dialogue box as soon as it starts. However, the activity always crashes.
The following is the code for the activity:

```
public class CheckInActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_in);
    getDialogue();



}

public void getDialogue(){

    //Pop dialogue

    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    View mView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_register, null);
    final EditText mPhone= (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    final EditText mPass= (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etPass);
    final EditText mRtPass= (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etRtPass);
    Button mRegisterButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);


    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog= mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
}
```

Here is the activity_check_in.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.shashank_pc.trial.CheckInActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the activity in the android_manifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".CheckInActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

The error message is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

**with**

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder= new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

or just add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to your application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: No use. Still crashing